# Mute audio file only at certain time intervals using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, ffmpeg

I have an audio.wav file that I will be playing through python. I have certain timestamps of the audio available in a timestamps.txt text file. I want to mute the audio at these timestamped duration like from 0:05 to 0:10,0:15 to 0:16 etc.

I have used the following code:

```
input=ffmpeg.input("audio.wav")
os.system('''ffmpeg -i {0} -af "volume=enable='between(t,5,10)':volume=0 output.wav'''.format(input))
```

I am not able to get the output file. Am I doing something wrong? Also how do I mute volume for many time intervals available in the text file.

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Take the whole file as a signal(if you mention file extension it would be helpful), set of values with timestamps, assign 0 to all the timestamps in the desired range.

```
from scipy.io import wavfile
fs, data = wavfile.read('./output/audio.wav')
```